# $routeprovider not working is not working as expected?

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

here is my code for route provider

```
 var externalapp = angular.module('Example', [  ]);

externalapp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider


    .when('/name', {
        templateUrl : 'views.html',
        controller: viewController'

    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/notavailable'
    });

} ]);
```

This is not working,it is not loading my html file. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: What error do you see in the console?

Comment: it is not showing any error@vishnu

Answer (score 0):

You should inject "ngRoute".

```
var externalapp = angular.module('Example', [ "ngRoute" ]);

externalapp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/name', {
        templateUrl : 'views.html',
        controller: viewController'
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/notavailable'
    });

 } ]);
```

For your Info: always see console log for errors.